# How do i use std.functional.memoize inside a class?

Tags: d

I'm unable to figure out how to use the memoize function inside a class.

```
import std.functional;

class A {
    int slowFunc(int a, int b) {
        return 0;
    }

    alias memoize!slowFunc fastFunc;
}

void main() {
    auto a = new A;
    a.fastFunc(1,2);
}
```

This gives an error when trying to compile: Error: need 'this' to access member slowFunc

How would I go about making this work?

Comment: and `alias memoize!(this.slowFunc) fastFunc;`?

Comment: Still get the same error when compiling

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't actually support this yet. We could file an enhancement request. Here's my experimental implementation:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.traits;
import std.typecons;
import std.datetime;

template isClassStruct(alias fun)
{
    enum bool isClassStruct = (is(fun == class) || is(fun == struct));
}

mixin template memoize(alias fun, uint maxSize = uint.max)
    if (isClassStruct!(__traits(parent, fun)))
{
    ReturnType!fun opCall(ParameterTypeTuple!fun args)
    {
        static ReturnType!fun[Tuple!(typeof(args))] memo;
        auto t = tuple(args);
        auto p = t in memo;
        if (p) return *p;
        static if (maxSize != uint.max)
        {
            if (memo.length >= maxSize) memo = null;
        }

        mixin("auto r = this." ~ __traits(identifier, fun) ~ "(args);");
        memo[t] = r;
        return r;
    }    
}

class A 
{
    int slowFunc(int a, int b) 
    { 
        int result;
        foreach (_; 0 .. 1024)
        {
            result += a;
            result += b;
        }
        return result;
    }

    mixin memoize!slowFunc fastFunc;
}

enum CallCount = 2048;

void main() 
{
    A a = new A;

    auto sw1 = StopWatch(AutoStart.yes);
    foreach (x; 0 .. CallCount)
    {
        a.slowFunc(100, 100);  // 11232 usecs
    }
    sw1.stop();
    writeln(sw1.peek.usecs);

    auto sw2 = StopWatch(AutoStart.yes);
    foreach (x; 0 .. CallCount)
    {
        a.fastFunc(100, 100);  // 302 usecs
    }
    sw2.stop();
    writeln(sw2.peek.usecs);
}
```

The timing comments are for my machine of course. :)

Comment: Btw this isn't semantically safe. Methods need the `this` reference because they typically have to look up internal class state (e.g. class fields). If that state changes between calls the hashed result won't be updated and you'll get back outdated results. But maybe there are legitimate use-cases for memoizing (@pure methods come to mind). Enhancement filed as: http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=8743

Comment: There is a way to clear the internal hash though, but you would have to do a boolean check on every invocation. For example: http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/abb6086f

Comment: Thank you muchly, especially for the rehash. That'll work wonders! :)

Comment: Btw I've used the wrong wording there. Rehash should be called `clear`, since it clears out the hash.